# Change style on orientation change on the fly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-styles

I made two style files for each orientation as shown bellow in the picture,

[image: img1]

but the problem is, when I flip the phone (Change the orientation to landscape for example) nothing changes, I tried `setContentView()` method inside`onConfigurationChanged` method, but I didn't achieve what I wanted.

This is my layout :

[image: img2]

1- Default Style :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="ExoMediaButton">
        <item name="android:scaleType">centerCrop</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ExoMediaButton.Previous">
        <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ExoMediaButton.Next">
        <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ExoMediaButton.Play">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_play_button</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ExoMediaButton.Pause">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_pause</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ExoMediaButton.FastForward">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_fast_forward</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ExoMediaButton.Rewind">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_fast_forward_back</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

2- Portrait Style :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="listStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_height">221dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="videoPlayerStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">216dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">8dp</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

3- for the landscape :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="listStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_height">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    </style>

    <style name="adsStyle">
        <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    </style>

    <style name="videoPlayerStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Can anybody gives us some advice or help me ?

Comment: Can you post the content of both styles.xml?

Comment: @UmangBurman I updated the post

Comment: Do you have the video player in Constraint layout?

Comment: @UmangBurman yes I do

Comment: You cannot change the player attributes from styles like that. Use constraint layout programmatically to solve your FullScreen issue.

Comment: @UmangBurman can you please post an answer showing me how to achieve that ? Please ?

Comment: Let me  paste some code from my project where I was making a YouTube kind of FullScreen thingy Okay. It may help you.

Comment: @UmangBurman Thank you

Comment: Hey do you know how to use a `Guideline?`

Comment: @UmangBurman I know how to make them

Comment: Okay cool. Check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

Check if your activty in manifest file has configChanges="orientation" specified.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: Yes it has 
` <activity android:name=".StreamingActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Step1: Add a `guideline` with width set to `match_parent` and give it an `id` then:

```
    binding.btnFullScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (binding.imgFullScreen.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ...
                        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)
                                binding.guideline6.getLayoutParams();
                        lp.guidePercent = 1;
                        ...
                    }
                }, 300);
            }
            else if (binding.imgNormalScreen.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ....
                        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)
                                binding.guideline6.getLayoutParams();
                        lp.guidePercent = 0.4f;
                        ....
                    }
                }, 300);
            }
        }
    });
```

**Explanation:** This code is written inside a button `onClick()` I'm setting my video-player to match_parent for width and height upto my guideline. So the code `lp.guidePercent = 1;` means the guideline will come to the end of the screen, bringing the video-player to full screen and similarly `lp.guidePercent = 0.4f;` means the guideline will come to 40% of the screen making it smaller and as you can see in the code, accordingly I'm setting my orientations.

I don't know if it's useful in your case, but this is how I do in mine.